# Error in opening the compiled module of HDF5

Tags: fortran, hdf5

I have a Fortran program with one of the files start with line `use HDF5`. The program was compiled and run on a particular cluster previously. Now, I am trying to compile the program in a different cluster, which has already `hdf5` installed in a particular location.

I assume that the issue is that the compiler could not understand the location of the `hdf5` installation directory. I tried specifying `hdf5` location by exporting with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` also. Still it does not work. Can someone help me figure what I doing wrong?

The compiler flags also include `-lhdf5_fortran` and `-lhdf5`.

**UPDATE:** The error list on compilation is long. But, the beginning of it looks like this:

```
lbe_io_hdf5.F90(7): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [HDF5]
  use HDF5
------^
lbe_io_hdf5.F90(82): error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [HID_T]
  integer(hid_t) :: file_id      ! File identifier
```

Comment: You have to tell us what you are doing in the first place. Otherwise we really have no idea what you are doing wrong...

Comment: **Never** use sentence *"it does not work"* in questions. What happens? Errors? Wrong results? Does it print something? Be specific.

Comment: I added the compile log.

Comment: Bbe aware that linking the library is not enough, you must set the include path so that the compiler knows where to search for the `.mod` files. You can use something like `-I the_path` (at least in gfortran).

Comment: I also included the location of `hdf5` installation with `-I /path/to/hdf5/lib` with the compiler flag. As you see, the issue starts with `use HDF5` itself, that the code does not know where the `hdf5` is located.

Comment: Is `/path/to/hdf5/lib` really the directory with the `.mod` files? They can be in some other `include` directory. That's why I point to the `.mod` files, bucause I know that it is the use statement.

Comment: No, the `.mod` files are in `src` directory of the code itself. I tried including `src` using `-I`. But no success. This `HDF5` specific `.mod` file is something I do not know where it is.

Comment: But you do need them, otherwise you are out of luck. Your code is looking for them

Comment: Even in the code working in previous cluster, there is no `hdf5.mod` file listed. This means the code just uses the `hdf5` header file and not `.mod` file. Is it so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126830/discussion-between-sathish-krishnan-and-vladimir-f).

Comment: were you able to to sort this issue? I'm facing a similar one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I have been trying to locate the `hdf5` header in wrong location. Using `locate hdf5.h` gave me the location of the header file and including the directory using `-I` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

HDF5 comes with a compiler wrapper `h5fc` for Fortran. For a single program file:

```
h5fc -o my_program my_program.f90
```

For separate compilation and linking:

```
h5fc -c file1.f90
h5fc -c my_program.f90
h5fc -o my_program file1.o my_program.o
```

If you want to call the compiler directly, check the flags given by

```
h5fc -show
```

If there is no `h5fc` command, it means that you have no Fortran-enabled HDF5 install.